# Лишние символы при POST-запросе

Tags: jquery, post, ajax

Здравствуйте! Отправляю POST-запрос на сервер простейшим образом:

```
$.post('base_load.php', {}, function(answer){
});
```

При получении ответа, имеются лишние символы в начале: ' \r\n' - тоесть пробел и символ переноса строки. Как избавиться от этого? Заранее спасибо!

**UPD:** вот код bd.php, именно после include("bd.php") добавляются лишние символы:

```
<?
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","02014007", "1100atm");
$db -> query('set character_set_client="utf8"');
$db -> query('set character_set_results="utf8"');
$db -> query('set collation_connection="utf8_general_ci"');
$db-> set_charset('utf8');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина была именно в include файла, решение выглядит так:

```
ob_start();
include("bd.php");
ob_end_clean();
```

http://www.denvo.ru/pub/programming/remove-spare-chars.html

Answer (score 0):

1. возможно в формировании ответа на этот запрос содержит пустую строку в самом начале.
2. Возможно у вас кодировка UTF-8, попробуйте перекодировать в UTF-8 (без BOM)